# My development environment was wiped out and I'm getting a series of errors in trying to fix it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm

So I was messing with gemsets with a friend of mine and I accidentally deleted a one. I wasn't sure what happened, so I just kinda brushed it off.

---

Then I went to run 'rails server' for my old app that I've been working on and nothing happens for like 2 minutes and then finally it spits out an error.

```
/Users/Nick/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/Nick/.rvm/bin/ruby: Argument list too long
/Users/Nick/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/Nick/.rvm/bin/ruby: Undefined error: 0
```

So then I did everything suggested below and I've gotten all kinds of errors. If I were to create a seperate question for every error I think I'd be making a mess of stackoverflow, so I want to give some kind of order to solving this here.

Right now I'm trying to backtrack and figure out what happened... Every time I run these different commands in an answer I'm changing things while I have no idea what's going on.

---

When I try to install a version of ruby I get this error:

```
apple-gcc42 is not available in PATH, try:

brew unlink apple-gcc42 && brew link apple-gcc42

and make sure that apple-gcc42 is available in your PATH:

which gcc-4.2
```

I read somewhere that installing xCode would solve this, so I installed it. Although I get the same error.

---

When I try to run the first suggestions from that error I get this:

```
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3... 0 links removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3... Warning: Could not link apple-gcc42.     
Unlinking...

Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/include/gcc
/usr/local/include is not writable. You should change its permissions.
```

When I run the second suggestions it returns

```
gcc-4.2 not found
```

---

Usually when I run 'ruby -v' or 'rails -v' it returns the version name. Now it just returns the exact same error as when I run 'rails s'

If I try to switch gemsets from default to global it says

```
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p125'
```

But then if I try to install it I get the same gcc error.

---

When I try to install rails I get this error about installing libyaml, which I've installed like 10 times:

```
➜  app3 git:(add_food_servings) ✗ gem install rails
 /Users/Nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb:4:in `<top (required)>':
 It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
 To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
 /Users/Nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-  
  p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require':  
 dlopen(/Users/Nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/psych.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/Nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/psych.bundle
```

---

My question is... what's going on and how can I get back to where I was when I could run rails s and just work on my app in peace!? lol

Comment: If your `Gemfile` is versioned in git *(it should be)* of course you can revert the changes.

Comment: Did you try removing Gemfile.lock and then running "bundle install"?

Comment: it says this when I try to run bundle install after deleting the Gemfile.lock file... /Users/Nick/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/Nick/.rvm/bin/ruby: Argument list too long
/Users/Nick/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/Nick/.rvm/bin/ruby: Undefined error: 0

Comment: What could have done this I wonder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got:

```
/Users/Nick/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/Nick/.rvm/bin/ruby: Argument list too long /Users/Nick/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/Nick/.rvm/bin/ruby: Undefined error: 0
```

shows that rvm ruby was not used, make sure you use ruby first before working:

```
rvm use ruby
```

if you want to use ruby which is defined for current directory project use:

```
rvm use --install --create .
```

the `--install` and `--create` flags will take care of missing ruby and gemset.

Comment: When I use "rvm use ruby" it tells me: To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.

Comment: So I did that. I installed libyaml with : rvm pkg install libyaml and then rvm reinstall all --force... Then I tried rvm use ruby but got the same error about installing libyaml

Comment: sounds like older version of rvm, make sure your rvm is up to date, current version is 1.21.19

Answer (score 1):

Let's clarify: The **Gemfile** cannot be changed from **gemset**

[Gemset](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) goal to provide you independent installation of gems for your application.

To work with RVM Gemset you should do the following:

1. Verify you have the latest **rvm** (run in your console):

   rvm get stable
2. Check which ruby version do you have: `rvm list` and gemsets: `rvm gemset list`
3. Let assume, the new gemset name is **myapp**. You should create it as following:

   rvm gemset create myapp
4. Add the following files inside your application root folder: **.ruby-gemset** and **.ruby-version**

   **.ruby-version** contains ruby version you want to use and **.ruby-gemset** contains gemset name
5. Close your console and open a new one. Go to you project folder and a new gemset should be ready. Repeat **step 2** to verify your gemset configured properly.
6. Install bundler:

   gem install bundler
   bundle install

**Example**: create **.ruby-*** config files:

```
echo "ruby-1.9.3-p429" > .ruby-version

echo "myapp" > .ruby-gemset
```

**Note:**

To make current gemset as default, do the following: `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p429@myapp --default`

Comment: See the example: create .ruby-* config files

Comment: what is that? lol I googled it and played with it in console but idk what that is.. a file path, a command phrase...

Comment: It's a command line in *nix OS. It creates a simple text file with the data output by echo

Comment: oh. Yea it didn't do anything. Gave me some error. I think my issue is that I accidentally deleted my default gemset. So rails, ruby, and even my rubygems installs were all wiped out.

Comment: @ninja08 run: gem install bundler  It will add bundle to your current gemset. Then, run: bundle install

Comment: I ran gem install bundler and it gave me the same error I get when I run "rails s" or "ruby -v". 

I tried to install ruby gems by downloading that file running the setup file but the same error I've mentioned already comes up.