# Capybara gem installation error in Ubuntu12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, capybara

Iam trying to execute command the `bundle install` it is showing the error message

```
Gem::InstallError: capybara requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
An error occurred while installing capybara (2.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara -v '2.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

so i upgrade my `ruby 1.8.2` to `ruby 1.9.3` and set this as default in `rvm.`

```
$ rvm list
rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

 $ ruby -v
```

iam getting `ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]`

same error obtaining when executing bundle install .

because of using `rvm` i use the command `gem install capybara -v '2.1.0'` iam getting

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory
```

later i tried `sudo gem install capybara -v '2.1.0'`

it successfully installed

so again i used the bundle install command to install remaing gems in my gem file it agian showing the same above mentioned error.

```
Gem::InstallError: capybara requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
An error occurred while installing capybara (2.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara -v '2.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Weird, it seems like you are not using the ruby version installed by rvm. Could you type `rvm use 1.9.3` and then type `ruby -v` ==> does that give the same version as in the `rvm list`? When using rvm you would never have to do `sudo` when installing gems.

Comment: iam getting this error while i use 'rvm use 1.9.3'

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example

Comment: yes i fixed the issues

Comment: So it is now ok? So your rvm was not installed correctly?

Comment: Yes ok now :-).          ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to set project dependent rvm settings.
Goto to your project folder and do the following:

```
echo "ruby-1.9.3-p448" > .ruby-version
echo "myapp" > .ruby-gemset
```

Close the console, reopen it and once again go to your project folder. Then, verify you ruby version is **1.9.3-p448** (`ruby -v`) and do the following:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

For more details, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812695/my-gemfile-was-emptied-after-messing-with-creating-gemsets/17813858#17813858)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have installed these before trying...

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev libqtwebkit-dev
```